# Syntax error when using input parameter to create procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I'm getting this error

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Parse error at line: 33, column: 15: Incorrect syntax near '@sas_token'

For reference here are the guides I am following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql-examples#b-shared-access-signatures-sas-with-crlf-as-the-row-terminator-windows-style-new-line

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-stored-procedures#stored-procedures-in-synapse-sql

I tried the commented part because I thought it didn't recognize the quotes but it still didn't work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bulk_load 
    @sas_token VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @sas varchar(500)
    --SET @sas = ''''+ @sas_token + ''''
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION;

    CREATE TABLE dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION 
    (
        model VARCHAR(20),
        col1 VARCHAR(15),
        col2 VARCHAR(3),
        col3 VARCHAR(255)
    );

    COPY INTO dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION
    FROM 'https://server.blob.core.windows.net/container/subfolder/file.csv' 
         WITH (FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',
               FIRSTROW = 2,
               CREDENTIAL = (
                             IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature',
                             SECRET = @sas_token --@sas also tried '''' + @sas_token + ''''
                            )
            );
END
```

This procedure will be called from Python like so:

```
def update_database(sas_token):

    #Runs the stored procedure to load the data from Azure storage to table.
    #Uses the password stored in user environment variable.
    
    server = 'server.database.windows.net'
    database = 'database'
    username = 'username'
    if 'server_password' not in os.environ:
        print("Missing environment variable 'server_password' containing database password.")
    password = os.getenv('server_password') 
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    sql = f'EXEC dbo.bulk_load, {sas_token};'
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    connection.autocommit = True
    connection.execute(sql)
    connection.close()
```

Comment: How are you calling this procedure?

Comment: You should get rid of the parenthesis enclosing your parameter definition of `@sas_token` in the very first line

Comment: It looks like SECRET cannot be set via parameter, but has to be hard coded...?

Comment: @rs I will be calling this procedure via python using pyodbc. Problem is that the procedure is not creating in the first place. The SAS token will change every 90 days and I have it stored in environment variable and it is read in from python then passed to this procedure and called.

Comment: Can you paste the full error you see with line number and all?

Comment: @rs yes I added it

Comment: @kindofhungry, I don't have access to the environment to try this, but could you try changing insert SQL to a  SQL string(@sqlcommand = '') and append token with quotes and call exec(@sqlcommand). I believe you may not be able to use parameters directly in that copy/insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoould work . I have created the Copy command dynamically and passing the SAS token to that . Once I have the copy command created I execute the command . The print statement , i used it as a test .
HTH

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bulk_load 
    @sas_token VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @sas varchar(500)
    --SET @sas = ''''+ @sas_token + ''''
    declare @query varchar(max) 
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION;

    CREATE TABLE dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION 
    (
        SSN VARCHAR(20),
        Name VARCHAR(15)
    );

    SELECT @query  ='
    COPY INTO dbo.ITEM_INFORMATION
    FROM ''https://server.blob.core.windows.net/container/subfolder/file.csv''
         WITH (FILE_TYPE = ''CSV'',
               FIELDTERMINATOR = ''',''',
               FIRSTROW = 2,
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
               CREDENTIAL = (
                             IDENTITY = ''Shared Access Signature'',
                             SECRET =  '''+@sas_token+'''
                             )
            );'
            print @query
            exec(@query)
END
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Dynamic query was exactly what I was looking for